# OneToOne JPA issue

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 2 class

```
public class User {
     @Id
     @Column(name = "id")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private String age;
     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
     private Address address;
}
```

and

```
public class Address {
     @Id
     @Column(name = "id")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;
     private String building;
     private String country;
     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
     private User user;
}
```

in my table address, I have a few rows.
When I insert table user with data

```
{
   "id":null,
   "name":"Foo",
   "age":"18",
   "address":{
      "id":1,
      "building":"Too",
      "country":"ABS"
   }
}
```

Table user have 1 row with address_id =1.
I insert same data as above
Table user have 2 row with address_id =1.
My answer is: why 2 table connected by one to one can happen  the above case?

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer here
[Why @OneToOne is allowing duplicate associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968294/why-onetoone-is-allowing-duplicate-associations)

Basically, `@JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")` alone doesn't serve the semantics of `one-to-one` in the database, you need to add `unique=true` into the `@JoinColumn`, which makes it `@JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = true)`.

Side-note: I suggest you drop your tables and then re-creating them before trying this out. If you are using Hibernate, you can set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create-drop`